# Algebraic forms on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves

On an elliptic curve defined by the equation,
$$E:y^2=x^3+a x +b$$
The algebraic form $dx/y$ is defined on the elliptic curve and it is a non-vanishing section of the (trivial) canonical bundle. From some physics literature, the form $xdx/y$, which has poles on the elliptic curve, together with $dx/y$ form a basis of the cohomology $H^1(E,\mathbb{C})$, which is not clear to me. Could anyone explain why the form $xdx/y$ defines an element of $H^1(E,\mathbb{C})$?

Edit: For example, in [the famous paper by Seiberg and Witten](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9407087.pdf), page 36, the sentence above formula (6.9).

Comment: Physicists say the most peculiar things....

Comment: Are you sure they aren't discussing a genus $2$ hyperelliptic curve? In that case $x \frac{dx}{y}$ is also regular.

Comment: @André3000 I have edited it and include where such a claim is from, a paper by Seiberg and Witten. It is definitely about a genus one curve in their original paper, the Seiberg Witten curve.

Comment: I think the point might be this: the residue of $x\,dx/y$ (at its only pole) is zero. So integration on homology-classes is well-defined.

Comment: Yes I agree with @peterag, the key word here is differential of the second kind, those where the residues at the poles are zero. If $\mathcal{M}$ is the sheaf of meromorphic function and $\mathcal{S}$ the sheaf of differential of the second kind $$ 0\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathcal{M}\overset{d}\longrightarrow \mathcal{S}\longrightarrow 0$$ is exact since a differential of the second kind has locally a primitive. The long exact sequence of cohomology gives a map $H^0(E,\mathcal{S})\to H^1(E,\mathbb{C})$. (Which I believe is always onto but I failed to show why).